# Audio_cache (audioplayers package) can't play audio file in android

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Today, I make application to play music on Android.
I have failed when using **MediaPlayer** to play an audio file; it can't play any file audio.
ON debug console:

```
I/flutter ( 5455): taped
E/MediaPlayerNative( 5455): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer( 5455): Error (1,-2147483648)
E/MediaPlayerNative( 5455): pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0xc83ffa40)
E/MediaPlayerNative( 5455): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayerNative( 5455): Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0xc83ffa40, mCurrentState=0
E/MediaPlayerNative( 5455): error (-38, 0)
2
E/MediaPlayer( 5455): Error (-38,0)
```

This is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FlatButton.icon(
            label: Text('ss'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit_outlined),
            onPressed: () {
              print('taped');
              final player = AudioCache();
              player.play('yagami.wav');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

On pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  audioplayers: 0.17.0
```

I've tried an older version of packages, but it didn't work out.
How to solve this problem?
**or any other packages to play audio on assets?**

Answer (score 0):

Something that might help is creating your player just once at the beginning, and not everytime you press the button as that defeats the purpose of AudioCache.
So remove `final player = AudioCache();` from the OnPressed function.